# Saving & embedding user's own javascript code

Tags: javascript, xss

I'm hosting a small service where people can create online calendars. I'm playing with the idea of allowing users to save & embed their own javascript/html/css to their calendars.

I'm a bit worried about the security implications - are there ways to use XSS etc so that the users javascript code could affect some other calendars besides the one where the code is embedded?

From the customers perspective, the JS on the page should be allowed to change all the aspects of the page.

I guess the safest way would be to only allow custom HTML/CSS, but the ability to modify the layout and functionality of the calendar with JS would be a nice feature to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be very dangerous, for the same reason that

> eval is **evil**

You're basically giving the user an oportunity to run malicious scripts.

Example: You are using AJAX to update something on your server. I come along, open up my trusty Firebug, see the AJAX request, and decide to wreck a little havoc, because thats what I do. I just rewrite the AJAX call, change the id of my calender to some random one, and bam, thats my dirty deed for the day.

Comment: eval is not the problem if he allows users to run javascript anyway. In fact, they don't need it.

Comment: Yes, however I am simply implying that this can be dangerous, **for the same reason** that eval is evil. ;)

Comment: My main concern isn't what the user does to his/her own calendar, but how they could affect other calendars / pages on my domain. Any worst case scenario examples?

Comment: First they could sniff your ajax requests, and then mimic them with dangerous data. I could find many interesting ways to make you pull your hair out if you gave me the chance (in fact you would be spoonfeeding me the chance if you allow it)

Comment: Yeah. I guess I'll fully disable it or force all embedded js to be validated by us beforehand. Thanks.